# What is the phrase or idiom for older people who still can function properly

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Sentence: Although he is 90 this year, he still _____: he can still walk, eat on his own.

Comment: *Copes* or *manages* works here. They work with the fairly low standard of performance being applied. I think *self-sufficient* is better applied to my 91 year-old mom, who still drives, does all her own shopping, cooks three meals a day, and manages her household in general.

Comment: From the description of the question I can see it's looking for something else, but in my head I just answered 'Not dead yet'

Comment: .he **is** still perhaps? And if you are going to add *he can still walk, eat on his own.*, you might as well just call him agile instead of looking for a specififc word

Comment: just "mobile" is often used here, too.

Comment: How about Autonomous ? (Directly translated from a French Idiom)

Comment: "He still is a person."

Answer (score 46):

[Sprightly](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sprightly) is often used in that sense:

> (especially of old people) energetic and in good health:
>
> - *He's a sprightly old man of 75.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 35):

My next door neighbour epitomises the vigour of the elderly who are still **spry**.

He is 94, is up every morning at 07:00, smartly dressed and off to the shops on his mobility scooter. He has just married my other neighbour this year, who is sixty-six.

Joe is one year older than his birth certificate shows since his birth was registered in 1924, a year after he was born in 1923.

Joe is **spry**.

> especially of an old person) active; lively.
>   "he continued to look **spry** and active well into his eighties"

[Google Dictionary](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-5211947/The-Queens-style-Philips-spry-ever.html)

> After missing out last year with a cold, the Queen’s back in style ... and Philip’s as **spry** as ever

[Daily Mail 25th December 2017](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-5211947/The-Queens-style-Philips-spry-ever.html)

Answer (score 25):

You have two different meanings here.

The question asked in your question title, mentions simply functioning properly, but the example sentence you have posted adds an extra dimension "on his own".

The best phrase to fit the meaning of your example sentence I would say is:

## [self-sufficient](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/self-sufficient)

Meaning:

> Able to provide everything you need, especially food, for yourself
> without the help of other people. -- Cambridge.

So your example sentence could be changed by adding "is self-sufficient":

> Although he is 90 this year, he still is self-sufficient: he can still
> walk, eat on his own.

I would however remove the last comma and replace with *and*, re-order slightly and also remove the second still.

> Although he is 90 this year, he is still self-sufficient: he can
> walk and eat on his own.

Answer (score 15):

Although he is 90 this year, he still ***[lives independently](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/independently)***.

From [EOLD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/independently):

> **independently**
>
> adverb
>
> 2. Without outside help; unaided.
>      *‘disabled people living independently in their own homes’*
>      *‘information for those who are travelling independently’*

Comment: "lives independently" relates to his living conditions a good deal more than his age or ability at said age.

"He is independent." is much better. A young man can live independently, it just means he's alone.

Answer (score 14):

*[Hale](https://www.onelook.com/?w=hale&ls=a)* is an old word meaning healthy, now largely fossilised in the phrase *hale and hearty*.

*[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hale)* defines *hale* as “healthy and robust”, and gives the following usage note:

> If you describe people, especially people who are old, as hale, you mean that they are healthy.
>
> *She is remarkable and I’d like to see her remain hale and hearty for years yet.*

I think this has the meaning you’re looking for, and also tends to be associated with age, so it has the right connotations.

The single word *hale* is usable on its own, but the phrase *hale and hearty* is probably more common. Either should work for your purposes.

Comment: OP is looking for a phrase or idiom - *hale and hearty* is a better answer than just hale.

Comment: Perhaps I'll edit to explicitly suggest both the individual word and the phrase.

Answer (score 13):

> Although he is 90 this year, he *still has all his faculties*: he can still walk, eat on his own.

faculty

[fak-uh l-tee]

noun, plural fac·ul·ties.

1. an ability, natural or acquired, for a particular kind of action:a
   faculty for making friends easily.
2. one of the powers of the mind, as memory, reason, or speech:Though
   very sick, he is in full possession of all his faculties.
3. an inherent capability of the body: the faculties of sight and
   hearing.
4. exceptional ability or aptitude: a president with a faculty for
   management.

[definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/faculties)

Comment: @AndyT I've added the additional definitions (from the very same link) which include "Inherent capability of the body" - equally, the first definition would cover abilities of the body. I disagree that "faculties" is only to do with the mind.

Comment: In the context of the phrase though, we're heading into colloquial interpretation. When a person whose health may be questionable is regarded as "having all their faculties," it's often presented in opposition to an inability to care for oneself. One might say "faculties" in equivalence to being "all there" but unable to interact with the world because of other disabilities.

Comment: @MarcL. Maybe, but I see the emphasis on "all", i.e. has "all his faculties" - that is can dance, walk, sing, complete a cross-word, use the toilet, play chess etc, etc.  So has full mental **and** physical faculties.

Comment: Hmmm. Your additional definitions (and those elsewhere) do back you up. In my experience though it only refers to mental ability, so it doesn't really work for me, as I'd misinterpret what was meant by someone using it for physical abilities.

Answer (score 11):

Some great answers here, but they all take a positive point of view of "functioning properly" - their words indicate function above and beyond the minimum.

Another options would be *[compos mentis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compos%20mentis)*, meaning "of sound mind; sane".

It is certainly used in British English to describe older folks who are still lucid and "functioning properly" from a mental perspective (even if they are otherwise infirm).

Comment: "compos mentis" (technical legalese) or "self-sufficient" (slightly loose) or "not senile" or "lucid" would all work. "Spr(ightl)y" doesn't ATQ.

Comment: I'd leave out the "properly"; I think you can simply say: _Although he is 90 this year, he still functioning._ You could even add a "well" at the end.

Comment: "compos mentis" is not English.

Comment: @insidesin "compos mentis" is one of countless latin phrases that are in common usage in English.

Comment: They are probably used in a small population of English users though, maybe just very British people. I'm British Australian and I've never heard it.

Comment: @insidesin - Yes, I'd hazard that it's a very British expression.  It comes from British law, where the term is used as a description for people who are able to manage their own affairs without external guidance, and particularly whether any will they create will be considered as having effect.  It's seeped into common usage, but that's where it's come from.

Comment: OP's example sentence is about being able to walk and eat. This is to do with a fully functioning body, not a fully functioning mind. "compos mentis" is therefore not an appropriate answer.

Comment: This seems to be the source/equivalent of the American legal construct "of sound mind". This doesn't get at the sense of *physical* capability in the question. We're not asking about the validity of Mom's will, but whether she needs to sell the house and go into assisted living.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to some other great suggestions here, I'd like to toss in "*sharp*" or "*sharp and able*" as a contender. I use it frequently to describe my wife's grandfather, who is in his 90s but still doesn't miss a beat and can do most things for himself.

**Edit:** My own answer revealed another possible answer, "doesn't miss a beat". It refers more to being mentally fit, but also implies being physically able as well.

Comment: And *(as) **sharp** as a tack/blade*

Comment: @k1eran That may actually be the root of the term "sharp". Definitely another good suggestion, either way.

Answer (score 4):

There's a popular idiom "***fit as a fiddle***".

> Although he is 90 this year, he still *is **fit as a fiddle***: he can
>   still walk, eat on his own.

TFD(idioms):

> **[fit as a fiddle](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fit+as+a+fiddle)** *BRITISH, AMERICAN* or **fit as a flea** *BRITISH*
>   If someone is as fit as a fiddle or as fit as a flea, they are very
>   fit and healthy.
>   Note: In the first two idioms here, 'fit' means
>   healthy and full of energy.
>   *He was nearly 80 and as fit as a
>   fiddle.*
>
> Note: This expression may originally have applied to a violin player,
>   or fiddler, rather than to a violin, or fiddle. The fiddler had to be
>   fit in order to play all evening at a festival or party.
>   Alternatively, 'fit' could mean 'suitable' rather than 'healthy', so
>   the original meaning may have been `as suitable for its purpose as a
>   fiddle is for making music'.
>
> Collins COBUILD Idioms Dictionary, 3rd ed. © HarperCollins Publishers
>   2012

Answer (score 3):

Speaking as someone who younger people may regard as old, how about “he/she is normal”?

Comment: "Normal" can be a very ambiguous term, in my opinion. It kind-of implies that it's "abnormal" to show signs of ageing. I do see where it's desirable, however, because virtually everyone wants to be treated with respect regardless of age.

Comment: Well put, @thanby. I confess, it was the ageist aspect of the original question that I allowed to provoke me.

Comment: @StephenWinnall: normal can be age-relative.  A normal baby is not walking at 6 months, and a normal 90 year old needs assistance in walking. I believe th OP is referring to an abnormal 90 year old.

Answer (score 2):

ambulatory (adjective)
1.
relating to or adapted for walking.